# Pulling and pushing between two google code repositories

Tags: mercurial, google-code

I'll start by quoting [google's blog](http://googlecode.blogspot.com/2009/10/mercurial-server-side-clone-support-for.html)

> Project owners can now create multiple repositories for their project, and they can choose to make any of those new repositories a clone of any of the project's other repositories. These project clones share the same commit access permissions as the original project and make it easier for project members to work together on new features. A common pattern in the Mercurial world is to place each "official" branch into a separate repository with naming conventions like "project-crew", "project-stable", and so on.

I've done exactly this. I have my default repository and then I've cloned that repository to a repo named "dev". I intend to use the default repository as my stable repo and then the dev repo as my primary development repo. Now I'm just wondering how on earth I should go about to pull and push between the default and the dev repositories?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to have its origin from [issue 2563](http://code.google.com/p/support/issues/detail?id=2563) (Multiple hg repositories per project), which triggered [issue 2946](http://code.google.com/p/support/issues/detail?id=2946) (Non-committer clones of Mercurial projects)

> There are definitely two separate feature requests being conflated here.
>
> - One is the ability for projects to have multiple repositories, repositories which may or may not be related to each other.
> - The other is the ability for non-project-members to host their own cloned versions of a project repository

The easiest way to push between the two repos is to:

- clone them locally
- [push/pull between them](http://www.selenic.com/mercurial/hg.1.html#push)
- push to their remote original repo from the respective local ones using the [right URL Path](http://www.selenic.com/mercurial/hg.1.html#url-paths)

Answer (score 1):

See the last page of Joel Spolsky's [Mercurial tutorial](http://hginit.com) for some examples on organizing your clones.